# The "d-none and d-sm-block" not working in the required area of the paragraph

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but what I need to do is make this paragraph disappear when showing on the small screens.

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <h2>Corporate Leadership</h2>
  <h3>Peter Pan <small>Chief Epicurious Officer</small></h3>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 d-none d-sm-block">
    <p>
      Our CEO, Peter, credits his hardworking East Asian immigrant parents who undertook the arduous journey to the shores of America with the intention of giving their children the best future. His mother's wizardy in the kitchen whipping up the tastiest dishes
      with whatever is available inexpensively at the supermarket, was his first inspiration to create the fusion cuisines for which
      <em>The Frying Pan</em> became well known. He brings his zeal for fusion cuisines to this restaurant, pioneering cross-cultural culinary connections.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is more code afterward but it isn't required, the problem is right here

Comment: It works fine for me when the media reaches the `576px` point or less. What is your actual problem?

Comment: Wait I changed something after copy pasting it and it wasn't working. Sorry!